# php form just for the one who is mailed

Tags: php

Im basically trying what I say in the title, that is:

I have a php file where you can put your email. After that, you receive an email with a link to other php file. This second file has a form and when you submit, a .txt is created with the information and I receive an email with that .txt.

What I want now is that only the users who click on the link that I send, get access to the form. Not just by writting on the nav http:myserverhost/mysite/myprivateform.php.

I did a research here and I guess that I have to work with sessions, like I use to, but now I need to avoid the information stored on the server.

How can I start a session for the user can access to the form for 1 hour for example, after clicking on the url.

Thanks,

Comment: When an email address is submitted, save the email address and a unique token to a table, along with the current timestamp.  The link to the form could have both the email address and the unique token.  That token and email could the be checked against a table of valid tokens.  A job running every X minutes could remove any tokens from the table that are over Y minutes/hours old.

Comment: Put the time that the form was submitted into a session variable. When they click on the link, check whether the current time is less than an hour after the time in the session.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the `$_SESSION` variable. Useful functions are: [session_start](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.session-start.php) and [session_destroy](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.session-destroy.php). I would create a class like this if I were you:

```
class SessionHandler {

    public static function start() {
        if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
            session_start();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static function destroy() {
        if (session_status() != PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
            session_destroy();
        }
    }

    public static function logIn($params) {
        start();
        $_SESSION["email"] = $params["email"];
        $_SESSION["token"] = $params["token"];
        $_SESSION["expiry"] = time() + 3600; //an hour later
    }

    public static function isValid() {
        return ((session_status() != PHP_SESSION_NONE) && 
                (intval($_SESSION["expiry"]) > time()));
    }

    public static function validate() {
        $valid = self::isValid();
        if (!$valid) {
            session_destroy();
        }
        return $valid;
    }

}
```

So, you need to generate a token and use `logIn` to link it to email address as well. Use `validate`/`isValid` to determine whether the user should have access to something.